# Check if an Apple device's camera supports slo-mo?

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

How can I check if an apple device (iPhones & iPads, at least) supports Slo-Mo recording or not? Currently I'm using screen size as a check for iPhones so that still leaves the iPhone 5s as well as iPhone SE. For iPads I'm facing similar kind of issues.

I'm using following code but this doesn't seem to work

```
NSArray *cameraDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo];

    for (AVCaptureDevice *camera in cameraDevices) {
        if ([camera position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
            if ([camera activeVideoMaxFrameDuration].timescale >= 120) {
                [self showChooseAlert];
            } else {
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"startVideoRecording" sender:self];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code:

```
NSArray *cameraDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDevice *currentDevice;

for (AVCaptureDevice *camera in cameraDevices) {
    if ([camera position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
        currentDevice = camera;
    }
}

for (AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format in currentDevice.formats)
{
    NSArray *ranges = format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges;
    AVFrameRateRange *frameRates = ranges[0];

    if (frameRates.maxFrameRate >= 120) {
        // Do Slow Motion stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: For this I'll have to activate camera first and then compare right?

Comment: @N4SK You can setup `AVCaptureDevice` and check.

Comment: I've updated the question.. please clarify where am I going wrong.

Comment: @N4SK do you want to start recording for Slow-mo camera only?

Comment: Actually I check if device support slo mo camera or not... if it does support I call `[self showChooseAlert];` which shows an alert asking user if he wants to record normal video or slo mo...

if the device does not support slo mo then user is simply taken to the controller with camera active in normal mode.

Comment: @N4SK on which device you are testing?

Comment: iPhone 6s and iPad Air

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173806/discussion-between-ivarun-and-n4sk).